# PHP and HTML: 000webhost error

Tags: php, html

Im building my website on 000webhost and with Zyro Builder and now i need some php code to get data from mysql database.

Im having this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in ....." every time i want to use something like this:

```
echo "<br/>";
```

I know that is possible, so why I can't use it? :S

Thank you for your attention.

```
<?php
// Connect to database server
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql4.000webhost.com","a8373599_gus","******","a8373599_lolgus") or die(mysql_error($con));

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Fail to connect: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
} else {
    echo "sucess!";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Player");
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "<br/>";
echo $row['UserName']." ".$row['Playername'];

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It's probably the surrounding code

Comment: If I remove it, code works well! I found that it doesn't let me use anything with html :S

Comment: @M. Coutinho: provide the minimum complete php file including `<?php` that reproduces the issue

Comment: The problem isn't with PHP code, It works well without just that line. But i will edit.

Comment: Try to create an empty file with <?php echo "<br/>" ?> and see if it works

Comment: <?php echo "<br/>"; ?> i guess :P And no it doesn't! :)

Comment: how about <?php echo "<br>"; ?>  ?

Comment: well actually i tried that before
But with ; missing i have another syntax error instead "?" i have: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in....

Comment: I mean try without a slash

Comment: Same thing... this is really annoying...

Comment: single quotes? <?php echo '<br>'; ?>

Comment: Already did and same error...

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then. The code is fine.

Comment: Its ok! IM thinking its their problem! Since im using their website builder. :S

Comment: Try ending the php ?> <br/> <?php and then the rest of the php code

Comment: Didn't follow your thought :S
That was an example, what i really need is to create a table, and i only know how to build html with php in that way, like so:

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
...

The problem is that they don't let me do this, I have no idea why. :S

Comment: Where you don't need to write php then there's no need to echo html with php. So if it's just html end php with ?> Then write your html tags and when you need php again then just open php <? Php

Comment: strange error.maybe there code generator modifies the echo statement through a macro or something. I'm guessing that. Try an alternative, like print '<br />'

Answer (score 0):

Try using the numerical instances,

Eg:

```
 echo $row[0]." ".$row[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I sent a ticket to them and they told me that might be a problem with their Site Builder. Your code and mine are 100% correct, but I can't use it on that website builder. I need to create a webpage without using that website builder. :)